# Check for join record in view for rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

So lets say I have a join table that joins users and items. The table is called "follows"

So lets say you're on a show view of a item. Is there a better way to check and see if a join record exists than:

```
@following = Follow.find_by_user_id_and_item_id(current_user.id,@item.id)
```

?

Comment: That's probably the most efficient way (provided that you have index on `(user_id, item_id)`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could rewrite it as

```
@following = Follow.where(user_id: current_user.id, item_id: @item.id).first
```

Functionality is the same, looks better.

Comment: Why does this look better? Returning an array and then calling the first makes less sense to me than using the find_by to call 1 record.

Comment: Matter of personal taste. Plus this is using modern Query Interface (as opposed to old-school dynamic matchers). We all like new stuff, don't we?